# Tab Fragments not showing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add tabs in a Fragment (for a bottom navigation bar). However, when I run the app, the tabs don't show up at all. Below is an image of the result:

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYfxW.png)

- Home.java -> the fragment that should display 2 tabs which includes BlankFragment.java
- CategoryAdapater.java -> sets up the tab names and fragments to display in each tab
- BlankFragment.java -> an empty fragment that is shown on each tab

**How can I get it to work?**

---

Home.java (the fragment that should show the tabs)

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    ViewPager viewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return rootView;
}

public Home() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

---

CategoryAdapater.java

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public CategoryAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return new BlankFragment();
    } else {
        return new BlankFragment();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return "Devices";
    } else {
        return "Numbers";
        }
    }
}
```

---

BlankFragment.java

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

public BlankFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post Home.java xml file

Answer (score 0):

adapter addFragment missing

```
    ViewPager viewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    BlankFragment frag= new BlankFragment ();
    adapter.addFragment(frag);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: There is no `addFragment()` method in `CategoryAdapter`, and it's unnecessary, anyway, as the `Adapter` is already creating the `BlankFragment` instances itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

ViewPager viewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
setupViewPager(viewPager);
CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
TabLayout tabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

return rootView;
}
public Home() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);
 }

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Devices");
adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Numbers");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
super.onDetach();
}
}
```

Update Home Class with this code